# Does System.Web.UI.WebControls.Xml use XslCompiledTransform?

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

I want to know if System.Web.UI.WebControls.Xml use XslCompiledTransform ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Resharper I saw 
`System.Web.UI.WebControls.Xml` is using
`XslTransform` and not `XslCompiledTransform`

so for performance problems I suggest to rewrite the control and add XslCompiledTransform.
and add a cache for the result of Xsl Compilation.